# How to use HttpClient to send an HttpResponse?

Tags: java, apache, apache-httpclient-4.x

I've seen some [great tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/)s on how to use HttpClient to execute `HttpRequest`s but I haven't been able to find anything similar on how to send `HttpResponse`s. I am creating my own simple web server and want to have this functionality.

It doesn't seem to be possible through `HttpClient` but I imagine that's because clients don't send responses. I was looking for a parallel `HttpServer` class but I couldn't find anything like it.

Does anyone know how to send `HttpResponse`s using Apaches Http libraries?

Comment: You should look into Servlets.

Comment: Why not use an existing embedded http server implementation such as jetty?

Comment: You need a web server ... Look at tomcat... it will send responses for the requests

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of examples

- [Embedded blocking server (HttpCore 4.3)](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.3.x/httpcore/examples/org/apache/http/examples/ElementalHttpServer.java) - classic I/O model
- [Embedded non-blocking server (HttpCore 4.3)](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.3.x/httpcore-nio/examples/org/apache/http/examples/nio/NHttpServer.java) - async I/O model, support for zero copy file transfer
- [Embedded blocking server (HttpCore 4.4a1)](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.4.x/httpcore/examples/org/apache/http/examples/HttpFileServer.java) - classic I/O model, support for pipelined request processing, simplified server bootstrap
- [Embedded non-blocking server (HttpCore 4.4a1)](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.4.x/httpcore-nio/examples/org/apache/http/examples/nio/NHttpFileServer.java) - async I/O model, support for zero copy file transfer, support for pipelined request processing, simplified server bootstrap